# Android game development framework Rokon

Tags: android, rokon

I am a beginner in Android game development, while searching i found Rokon, a framework for android game development. It has very nice five tutorials for beginning, done that all now i need some  more tutorials so that i can learn more, some more complicated tasks.

Now where to find other resources to continue on Rokon, or if there exists some other framework with more available tutorials ?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you already have the basics, why not think about your own game and simply start it? Or try to copy an already existing game to learn more.

Tutorials are mostly to learn the basics only, everything else should be done by yourself...